# Im confused regarding %p specifier

Tags: c, pointers

```
  #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void) 
    {

       int i=10;
       printf("%p",i);
       return 0;
    }
```

output:-

```
0xa
```

%p - I have read %p is used to print pointer in printf, but here i is an integer,and also there is no pointer declared so how "0xa" gets output.

Comment: Wrong input, wrong output. In general, `printf` only prints whatever you put into it. Here you put an integer in it and this integer is printed. As `%p` is not proper format specifier for integer, you also have undefined behaviour

Comment: By the way, nothing wrong with the question IMHO. Nicely written and a compilable example.

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour of your code is *undefined* since an `%p` is not an appropriate format specifier for an `int` type.

The compiler is allowed to do *anything*, which includes optimising your code to `int main(){}`.

Answer (score 2):

Technically it is undefined behaviour because `%p` is the wrong format specifier for an `int`.

But if your platform is 32 bits, then `%p` usually boils down to printing the supplied value in hexadecimal on most implementations and therefore `printf("%p", 10);` will usually print `0xA` or `0x0000000A` on these implementations.

Anyway, don't use unmatched format specifiers, because even if it appears to work, it results in [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Rationalising UB is a dangerous art. IMHO more care needs to be taken here. E.g. `int` might be 16 bit on a 32 bit platform. What then? But you do describe the output plausibly, so perhaps your answer is more helpful than mine. Have an upvote.

Comment: @Bathsheba yes `int` might be 16 bits, although I'm not aware of such an implementation. But anyway I wrote _usually_.

Comment: Our old friend Turbo C++ has 16 bit ints, and lots of schools seem to use it.

Comment: Isn't Turbo C++ a 16 bit platform? Maybe I'm wrong. Anyway I really wonder why those schools use Turbo C++ and not gcc or clang.

Comment: FWIW, if OP actually wants to get the output he gets, proper formatting would be `"%#x"`. Though care should be taken with signedness.